# Combobox with dynamic district in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, yii, combobox

I'm a newbie in Jquery and Yii framework. I have a problem with this issue.

### Tables:

There are two tables

**CITY:**  `city_id`,   `name`

**DISTRICT:** `dis_id, city_id, name (city_id is foreign key of CITY(city_id))`

Anyone can help me how to create 2 combobox when I select city name contemporaneously It shows  districts. 
Any code for example?

Thanks in advance.

Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: Hi Khue Pham, I seen 2 possible solutions according to your question. #1 Preloaded all data once user load the page, #2 Query only when CITY is selected. Which scenario were you looking at?

Comment: hi Eric, thank you for your comment. Well, I want to show 2 dropdownlists which related, example: **City A** has 2 **districts B and C**. And when I choose city A in first dropdownlist, second dropdownlist will show B and C. Do you mean that I must join 2 tables???

Comment: Hi I'm Eric not Ayaz. Mechanism for performance may vary from your case but to make it easier scenario #2 are more adaptable. Let me craft some basics for your understanding later. Meanwhile please refer to this URL for how to use JQuery with AJAX. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 1):

Try to read as below,

//Your Jquery Ajax should look like this

```
$("#firstcomboboxid").change(function() { //when your first combobox made changes
    $.post( "/controllername/functionname", $( "#yourform" ).serialize(), function(data){        
        //Response from server after query
        if(data.result == 'success'){
            $("#secondcomboboxid").empty(); //Make sure the combobox is empty
            $.each(data.district,function(i,val)){
                $("#secondcomboboxid").html("<option value='"+i+"'>"+val+"</option>"); //bind every of them into combobox
            }
        }
    },'json');
}
```

// Your Controller {controllername as of now}

```
public function functionname(){ //functionname to be replace
    /* Starts your query here */

    $result = .....; //For example we will use $result as variable and assuming it will be an array as result.
    /* End of your query */

    exit(json_encode(array('result' => 'success','district' => $result))); //Return with JSON encode
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Remember to give a check on the answers.

Comment: I see, but I don't know how to post my code here @@. Sorry about that